# Singleton module or class methods + class instance variables for singleton-like behaviour in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, singleton, class-method, class-instance-variables

I need class that has singleton behaviour.

What's the difference between using the Singleton module...

```
require 'singleton'

class X
    include Singleton

    def set_x(x)
        @x = x
    end

    def test
        puts @x
    end
end

X::instance.set_x('hello')
X::instance.test
```

...and using class methods and class instance variables?

```
class X
    def self.set_x(x)
        @x = x
    end

    def self.test
        puts @x
    end
end

X::set_x('hello')
X::test
```

Comment: IMHO the main difference is communicating the intent of what you are trying to do, which is more obvious if you `include Singleton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing, as you wrote your code--but a singleton is a class that only allows a single instance. Nothing in the second code snippet disallows instantiation of multiple instances.

Comment: So in the first code snippet it's still possible to write 't = X.new'?

Comment: Seems like it'd be quicker to try it, no? But no, it isn't possible (at least without an error). The singleton part of it removes the `new` method from public view--that's why there's an `instance` method. An alternative would have been to have `new` return the single instance, but it's arguably less communicative.

Comment: Yeah, it would have been quicker to try it. I just wanted to make sure that that was the major difference.